# Flip a Ui.Image in Dart

Tags: image, flutter, dart, canvas, flip

I am building a app that uses a canvas to render images. To do so, I need to load them using a Ui.Image object. Is there anyway to horizontally flip the image when I load the image? Maybe by reversing the byte array or something?

Here is my Function for loading images:

```
static Future<ui.Image> loadImage(String imagePath) async {
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load(imagePath);

    final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.view(bd.buffer);

    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);

    final ui.Image image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;

    return image;
  }
```

I've heard that there's a way to horizontally flip an image using canvas, but it's an expensive operation and efficency in redrawing the canvas is important to my project. Is there any way to flip the image while it's being loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can draw your image with `paintImage()` function which can be used inside flutter canvas, which make it easier to do anything image.

```
paintImage(
    canvas: canvas,
    rect: _rect,
    image: _img,
    flipHorizontally: true,
);
```

Where the parameter `_rect` describe the position and size where the image will be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
Transform(
alignment: Alignment.center,
transform: Matrix4.rotationY(math.pi),
child: Image.asset('image path.png'),
)
```

Comment: I'm trying to render the image on a canvas so unfortunately I can't use other widgets

Comment: Can you post your code here please?

Comment: @JohanDonkersloot and if you dont like to play with `Matrix4` api you can also directly scale canvas with `canvas.scale(-1, 1)`

Comment: @pskink
I appreciate the reply, but since the canvas operations can be expensive, I am really looking to flip the image on the byte level.